# Groupby agg keep blank value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Let say I have got a dataframe called df

```
     A    10
     A    20
          15
          20
     B    10
     B    10
```

The result I want is

```
     A    30
          35
     B    20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine your blanks are actually `NaN`s, then use `dropna=False`:

```
df.groupby('col1', dropna=False).sum()
```

If they really are empty strings, then it should work with the default.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'A', float('nan'), float('nan'), 'B', 'B'],
                   'col2': [10, 20, 15, 20, 10, 10]})
df.groupby('col1', dropna=False).sum()
```

output:

```
      col2
col1      
A       30
B       20
NaN     35
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by custom group and aggregate columns.

Suppose your dataframe with 2 columns: 'col1' and 'col2':

```
>>> df
  col1  col2
0    A    10  # <- group 1
1    A    20  # <- group 1
2         15  # <- group 2
3         20  # <- group 2
4    B    10  # <- group 3
5    B    10  # <- group 3
```

```
grp = df.iloc[:, 0].ne(df.iloc[:, 0].shift()).cumsum()
out = df.groupby(grp, as_index=False).agg({'col1': 'first', 'col2': 'sum'})
```

Output result:

```
>>> out
  col1  col2
0    A    30
1         35
2    B    20
```